# EWS API calls returning "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Fanout timed out"

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are using a forked version of [exchangelib](https://github.com/nylas/exchangelib) to make EWS API calls and we are seeing the [Exchange Online/Office 365 server](https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx) returning the following error:

```
An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Fanout timed out
```

for multiple API calls and we couldn't find any reference to that error message online.

Did anyone ran into this before and know more about what could be the root case? Or would you know where we could look to learn more (e.g. logs)?

Thanks!